# C++ Passing a 2d c-string element into a function

Tags: c++

What should be the proper way of doing this? Here's an example code of what I tried.

main

```
const int SIZE = 10;
char a[10][SIZE]; //assume this array already hold some character strings
fnc(a[2][SIZE]);
```

function

```
void fnc(char a[SIZE]){   
cout << a;
}
```

I feel that I might be close, but I couldn't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Nope. Compiler still returns invalid conversion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function call in main should not be:

```
fnc(char a[2][SIZE]);
```

i am guessing you want to print the string at a[2]. Hence your function call should be:

```
fnc(a[2]);
```

Comment: Still getting conversion error. I  tried changing/removing braces inside the function but still not working.

Comment: can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? please specify the entire error

Comment: Actually you're right. I just removed the [SIZE] part in the function and changing fnc prototype and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 2D array like this:-

```
char array[10][10];
void passToFunc(int a[][10])
{
    // ...
}
passToFunc(array);
```

Sorry for mis-interpretation:-

You can do it by :-

```
 void passElement( char x )
 {
   //do something with x.
 }
  passElement( arr[1][1] );   //assume you want to pass 2nd element of 2nd 1-dimensional array.
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know how to pass a whole array into a function. What I need to figure out is how to pass a specific element within that array to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you want to pass an element from 2d char array to a function. So just pass two arguments to your function which indicate the position of your element.
`void fnc(int p1,int p2)`
Your whole code will look like this.
`const int SIZE = 10;
char a[10][SIZE];
fnc(2,0);`

**function**

`void fnc(int p1,int p2){
cout << a[p1][p2];
}`
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your application never initializes the strings so there may be garbage being printed out.  Here is an example that I did that works for me.  Its a C++ app written using visual studio 2013.

Note that I initialized the strings to only 9 places in a 10 place array.
That is to account for the null terminator required for each string.

I hope this helps.

```
// TestApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

const int xSIZE = 10;
void fnc(char*);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char a[10][xSIZE];
    strcpy(a[1], "012345678");
    strcpy(a[2], "abcdefghi");
    fnc(a[2]);
    return 0;
}
void fnc(char a[])
{
    cout << a<<endl;
}
```